# Degree of sub sheaf of locally free sheaf is bounded

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, algebraic-vector-bundles

Let $X$ be smooth projective curve over a field $k$.

Let $\mathcal F$ be a finite rank locally free sheaf on $X$. Now, consider the set
$ D = \{\operatorname {deg}(\mathcal G) : \mathcal G$ is a subsheaf of  $\mathcal F \}$. Why is set $D$ bounded, i.e. $\operatorname {sup} D$ is less than $n$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Can you do this if $\mathcal{F}$ is of rank one?

Comment: No, I don't how to do it for one. I guess if I could this for rank one that would imply it for the general case as the degree is the degree of the determinant bundle.

Comment: In the rank one case, if $G\subset F$, then $F\otimes G^{-1}$ has a section, so its degree which is $\deg F-\deg G\geq 0$.